# GWT: Mobile usability issues: Resolving the "Content not sized to viewport" issue

Tags: google-search-console, best-practices, responsive-webdesign

Google Webmaster Tools (GWT) flagged this error on my client's **responsive** website. The errors exclusively appear on pages with large tables of data. The developers took a quick look and weren't able to determine identify any CSS that might be causing the issues. The page doesn't have any horizontal scrolling and we feel we are adhering to [Google's guidelines](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/size-content-to-the-viewport) (and the [author's relevant blog post](http://petelepage.com/blog/2012/12/using-meta-viewport/)).

**Has anyone had a similar experience ? How did you resolve the issue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The robots.txt file has to allow access to the CSS files, otherwise Google cannot evaluate mobile usability.

This would have been picked up automatically if Google's call-to-actions were to the Mobile Friendly tool instead of the PageSpeed Insight tool: https://www.google.co.uk/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/

Please see Google's webmaster guidelines for more information: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769